# Can a path have 2 different fill colours at a certain point?

Tags: javascript, css, svg, d3.js, path

I have an area chart.

I would like it to change the fill colour at a certain point along the x axis.

Example: If a value is greater than a certain value, change the fill colour of the path from this point on.

I have been trying the following:

```
.attr("fill", function (d, i) {
    if (d.timeFrom < d.beforePredictedDate ){
        d3.select(this).style("fill", function (d,i) { 
            return "purple"
        });
    }
    else{
        d3.select(this).style("fill", function (d,i) { 
            return "green"
        });
    }
}
```

The ideal outcome would produce something that enables the following:

[image]

Comment: You can do it with a linearGradient but it's better to use two paths.

Comment: @RobertLongson Can it not be done with a simple path?

Comment: @RobertLongson Ended up using 2 paths.

Answer (score 1):

As Robert said, you can make a fill like that using a linearGradient that starts and ends at the colour boundary.

```html
<svg>
    <defs>
        <linearGradient id="grad">
            <stop offset="70%" stop-color="black"/>
            <stop offset="70%" stop-color="limegreen"/>
        </linearGradient>
    </defs>

    <circle cx="150" cy="75" r="75" fill="url(#grad)"/>
</svg>
```

But for general paths, working out where to position the gradient stops may end up being a pain. So it is probably simpler and better in most cases to use two paths - as Robert said.

Comment: Any idea how to do this with d3?

Comment: Ended up using 2 paths.